# pkill inside the cron script kills next commands

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, kill

I have a hash.sh file which runs as cron job. Inside the script I need to call pkill to clean some redundant process. But when pkill is called whole script ends up immediately and next commands are not executed. Here is the script with one pkill at the end

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /opt/selenium-server/

# -c returns number of lines in grep result
countHub=$(ps -x | grep -v "grep" | grep "selenium-server" | grep "role hub" -c)
countNodes=$(ps -x | grep -v "grep" | grep "selenium-server" | grep "role node" -c) 

# selenium server jar path
jarFilePath="/opt/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"



# if selenium server HUB is in ps -x result
if [ $countHub -eq 1 ] 
then 


  # if there is NO NODE
  if [ $countNodes -eq 0 ] 
  then 
    
    # start two new nodes
    java -jar $jarFilePath -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
    java -jar $jarFilePath -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
    exit 0    
  
  # if there is only ONE NODE
  elif [ $countNodes -eq 1 ] 
  then 
  
    # start one new node
    java -jar $jarFilePath -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
    exit 0
    
  fi  
    

else # if there is NO HUB start new hub and two new nodes


  # kill all possible hubs and nodes for sure
  pkill -9 -f "selenium-server"

  # Start new hub
  java -jar $jarFilePath -role hub & 
  java -jar $jarFilePath -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
  java -jar $jarFilePath -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
  exit 0

fi
```

How to write it correctly? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is it perhaps because the string `selenium-server` appears in the path to your script, and `-f` causes `pkill` to match against the full path?

Comment: Changing your script name could solve this issue

Comment: It seems it is the reason. Script kills itself because of path name. Try to change it.

Comment: Yes but may be little cleaner for humans :)

Comment: Dont know how to do it. This is simple.

Comment: I can I made it like `pkill -9 -f $jarFilePath` Now I thing I remove the pkill. It is not necessary.

Comment: To match "`selenium-server`", without matching "`selenium-server`", use `grep '[s]elenium-server'`. The `[s]` matches the single character "`s`", but the "`[]`" break the match.